# error on updating subform Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a main form and a sub form in a datasheet view. They are linked through 2 ID fields which form the primary key for the table attached to the main form.

I call the main form the first time to insert records in to the DB and then call it later to update the records. I'm able to update the record on the main form but as I click on the subform I get an error saying `"Cannot perform cascading fucntion. It would result in a duplicate key in table"`

Curiously, I do not get this error when I try to update the data in the first record in the database.

**Relationships**

[image]

**Subform properties**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, Size_No in Sizes table is not Autonumber data type. If so, Access automatically inserts values for Order_ID and Step_No for new record in Sizes, but Size_No remains Null, so when you insert second record, all 3 values in primary key columns are the same and Access generates error. You need to insert new not null value in Size_No in `BeforeInsert` event of Sizes subform. The value should be unique for each pair of Order_ID and Step_No

Comment: Thanks for your reply! You are right about Size_No not being an autonumber.  I manage the size_no numbering myself by incrementing it. I checked the DB for duplicates but there are none. I think if there were duplicates it would have stopped me from entering data. But here it is letting me enter data but not update it.

Comment: Try to temporary delete from main form query tables Incoming and Order in order to exclude problems from this part of query and try again. If error persists, try to debug the application and check, which keys it tries to insert to sizes. You can also for debugging temporary drop primary key from Sizes and allow any values in key fields. It may allow to understand what's wrong.